# Spring Batch - Pass data between Processor & Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've a spring batch which contains *reader->processor->writer*.

Data passed b/w is of type `Emp`:

```
class Emp {
    iny id;
    String name;
    EmpTypeEnum empType;    // HR, Dev, Tester, etc.

    // getters and setters
}
```

As a simple batch data is read from a CSV file in `Reader`, some processing inside `Processor` & and an output CSV file is written by `Writer`.

But apart from this output CSV file, I want to generate a secondary output file which only contains count of each `EmpType`, i.e. Total number of HR, Dev & Tester.

I was thinking of performing the counting within the `processor` only, like:

```
public class EmpItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Emp, Emp> {

    int countHr;
    int countDev;
    int countTester;


        @Override
        public Person process(final Emp emp) throws Exception {

        if (item.getEmpType.equals(EmpTypeEnum.HR) {
            countHr++;
        } else if // .....

        // other processor on emp

            return emp;
        }

}
```

But as you can see I can only return `Emp` from `Processor`, so how can I pass *countHr, countDev, etc.* from processor & use it to create secondary file?

Please suggest. If you think any other approach will be better, please suggest.

*Thanks*

Comment: Hello, if you want to write the counter only at the end, you could create a listener and once the job is finished, in the listener, retrieve the counter from context (the counter that you have to update on each item processing) and then write the it on file

Answer (score 4):

You could use  `ItemWriteListener` and `JobExecutionListenerSupport` for this.

1. Define a ItemWriteListener , Which will be called after calling your writer every time.
2. In this Listener update a counter in execution context every time
3. Write a JobExecutionListener which will be called after the whole job is completed, where you can read the value from execution context and do further processing.

   ```
   @Component
   @JobScope
   public class EmployeeWriteListener implements ItemWriteListener<Emp> {

     @Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
     private ExecutionContext executionContext;


     @Override
     public void afterWrite(final List<? extends Emp> paramList) {

        final int counter =
             this.executionContext.getInt("TOTAL_EXPORTED_ITEMS", 0);
         this.executionContext.putInt("TOTAL_EXPORTED_ITEMS", counter + 1);
       }

     }
   }



   @Component
   @JobScope
   public class EmployeeNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport  {

   @Override
   public void afterJob(final JobExecution jobExecution) {

     jobExecution.getExecutionContext()
         .getInt("TOTAL_EXPORTED_ITEMS")
     ...................
      }
    }
   ```

You should register these listeners when you declare your step and job .

```
this.jobBuilders.get("someJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(new EmployeeNotificationListener())
        .flow(this.getSomeStep()).end().build();
//instead of new(..) you should Autowire listener

public Step getSomeStep() {

  return stepBuilders.get("someStep").<X, Y>chunk(10)
      .reader(this.yourReader).processor(this.yourProcessor)
      .writer(this.yourProcessor).listener(this.EmployeeWriteListener)
      .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need multple `ItemWriter`'s to process two different writing tasks. You can easily use `CompositeItemWriter` which has the capability of holding list of different ItemWriter within it. And on each item it will call all it's `ItemWriter`.

In your case,

1. Make two `FlatFileItemWriter` - one for your normal CSV output & other for your statistics.
2. Then create `CompositeItemWriter<Emp>` object and add both these `FlatFileItemWriter<Emp>` into it using this method of it - `public void setDelegates(List<ItemWriter<Emp>> delegates)`
3. Use this `CompositeItemWriter` as you `ItemWriter` in the step

So, when your `CompositeItemWriter` is called it will delegate to both the `ItemWriter` in order you have added to the list.

Job done :)

Comment: Your answer seems to make sense but I cannot clearly figure out everything. Do you mind attaching an example?